# Cannot run percy snap shot test in Testcafe error message: npm ERR! missing script: test:percy

Tags: javascript, testing, npm, npm-install, testcafe

I'm running my first test using percy snapshot using the following command

```
npm run test:percy
```

. I got the following error message:

```
xxx.xxx@LPG002572 TC-Visual % npm run test:percy
npm ERR! missing script: test:percy

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/xxx.xxx/.npm/_logs/2020-04-06T16_11_45_122Z-debug.log
jacqueline.george@LPG002572 TC-Visual % npm run test:percy
npm ERR! missing script: test:percy
```

However my `package.json` which I double checked seems to be correct. What did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

```
{
  "name": "tc-visual",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Visual testing with TestCafe and Percy.io",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "percy exec -- testcafe chrome ./tests"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "TestCafe",
    "percy"

  ],
  "author": "xxx xxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@percy/testcafe": "^0.2.0",
    "testcafe": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: What's unclear from the message? You do indeed *not* have a script named `test:percy`, just one named `test`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. I just updated the question with the command i used to run this test. this was the command in the training course that was used.

Comment: Yes, the command you used is clear from the output. It *doesn't match* the package file.

Comment: that's what I thought on reflection it didn't make any sense to me either.  So what should I run instead. I'm a novice with percy only started using it today. so what should I run instead.

Comment: Well what *is* the name of the only script in your package file?

Comment: the name of my script is percy.tests.js. When I saw that naming convention I was puzzled. I personally wouldn't name a file like that.

Comment: The name *of the script*. Look at your package file. What's the key in scripts? Is it test:percy?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem is that  under 'tests' in the package Json.  I made an omission.   This is very easy to do.  So  if anyone else is experiencing this issue please be careful because when you modify your package json. As you can see in the updated code I added `test:percy`

Please see the updated package json with the correct information

```
{
  "name": "tc-visual",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Visual testing with TestCafe and Percy.io",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test:percy": "percy exec -- testcafe chrome ./tests"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "TestCafe",
    "Percy"

  ],
  "author": "Author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@percy/testcafe": "^0.2.0",
    "testcafe": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$ percy exec -- testcafe chrome ./tests
'percy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1
```

.

```
yarn add percy or npm install percy
```

Also percy client was needed after getting this error: Unsupported Percy CLI version, disabling snapshots.

```
npm install --save-dev @percy/cli
```